# Youtube iframe embed does not play on Android browser

Tags: android, iframe, youtube, android-browser, android-youtube-api

I am having an issue with Android 4.0.3's native mobile browser inability to play the suggested embed code from YouTube,

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/mEvvc80ZYU8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Safari mobile, Chrome mobile on iOS works as expected. Chrome mobile on Android is working as expected. Android's native browser on tablet, plays the iframe as expected.

Comment: Have you tried forcing the link to the page that the video is embedded in to open in a specific browser? Maybe something along the lines of what this answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59318993/how-can-i-force-open-external-link-in-browser-instead-of-app

Answer (score 1):

Add http protocol:

src="//www.youtube...
to
src="http://www.youtube...

Comment: Thus far, adding http protocol is the best recommendation. Thanks @Maciek

Answer (score 0):

It sounds weird but in my case, just add

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

somewhere before `loadUrl()` and it works.

Comment: I'm not calling, loadUrl(). I simply cut and paste from the Youtube channel. Any other suggestions?