# How can I force open external link in browser instead of app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile

My mobile website provides external links like YouTube.
Depending on browsers, It opens on the web browser or corresponding app.

But I want to force open the link in current browser instead of app.

Example - Chrome Mobile browser always open Installed Youtube App when I open link like 'https://m.youtube.com';

- Im using React now.

Answer (score -1):

This popular GitHub Gist from 2011 (with updated code from 2018 added in a comment near the bottom) is for HTML documents loaded into WebViews, but seems to be what you're after: https://gist.github.com/kylebarrow/1042026

The technique used is to intercept the hyperlink click, cancel the default navigation (which would cause the "Open in YouTube?" prompt to appear) and then navigates by setting `window.document.location.assign` (which is **not** the same thing as `window.location`). I'm not a Mobile Safari expert, but I suspect that Mobile Safari won't prompt to open in an app if `document.location` is set instead of `window.location`).

Put this code in a script function that runs after the document's DOM has loaded (i.e. `DOMContentLoaded` or in an inline script at the end of the rendered HTML.

```
    const isMobileSafari = ( ( ua ) => ua.match(/iPad/) || ua.match(/iPhone/) )( window.navigator.userAgent );
    if( isMobileSafari ) {
        const hyperlinks = document.querySelectorAll( 'a:link' );
        for( let anchor of hyperlinks ) anchor.addEventListener( 'click', onHyperlinkClickPreventAppOpen );
    }

    function onHyperlinkClickPreventAppOpen( ev ) {
        const el = ev.target;
        if( el.href && ( el.href.startsWith( "http:" ) || ( el.href.startsWith( "https:" ) ) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            window.document.location.assign( el.href );
        }
    }
```

If you want to intercept clicks in hyperlinks added after the document was loaded then do something like this:

```
document.addEventListener( 'click', onDynamicHyperlinkClickPreventAppOpen );

function onDynamicHyperlinkClickPreventAppOpen ( ev ) {
    const el = ev.target;
    el = el.closest( 'a:link' ); // In case the 'click' event was raised by a descendant of an <a>
    if( !el ) return;

    const fakeEvent = { target: el, preventDefault: ev.preventDefault };
    onHyperlinkClickPreventAppOpen( fakeEvent );
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question. I tried ur suggestion above, but It doesn't work. and I tested on chrome browser not safari

Comment: `document.location.assign` doesn't help on Android+Chrome